# Saving line numbers of texts in JSON/Database without breaking up the text according to lines?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, data-structures, database-design

I have a text. The text has different lines-number, based on some book in print. My app will also need to display it like this. E.g.:

```
1 This is a sentence. Here is another. The third sentence   1
2 stretches over multiple lines and is only completed in    2
3 line number 3. Then we have a fourth and fifth sentence,  3
4 but then that's it. That's it.                            4
```

The text needs to be saved in some backend somewhere. I could save the whole text line by line:

```
text = {
{
  line_no: 1,
  content: "This is a sentence. Here is another. The third sentence", 
}, 
{ 
  line_no: 2,
  content: "stretches over multiple lines and is only completed in", 
}, 
etc...};
```

However, this solution is also somewhat ugly. Moreover, the project I am working on requires me to view sentences as the basic units to work with. For example, I will often need to information pertaining to *a sentence* and almost never work with lines, -apart from when I need to render the text on the screen. So let's say I need to save the number of words of a particular sentence. It would be much easier to split the text along sentences:

```
{
  sentence_no: 1,
  content: "This is a sentence.",
  word_count: 3
},
{
  sentence_no: 2,
  content: "Here is another.",
  word_count: 3
},
{
  sentence_no: 3,
  content: "The third sentence stretches over multiple lines and is only completed in line number 3. ",
  word_count: 15
},
etc....
```

I am struggling to understand how I could use this latter approach (or something somewhat similar), and still save line numbers somewhere. I would greatly appreciate some advice here!

Comment: and what do you want? line numbers or sentence numbers?

Comment: Store a table of the actual lines, and another table for each sentence. The sentence table would have the line number and character position of the start and end of each sentence.

Comment: @NinaScholz As I said, i need to display the sentences according to `line numbers`, but will need to work more often with sentences as the basic units of the app.

Comment: Add the snippet what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Pointy That sounds interesting. Could you explain a bit more how this would roughly look like in practice / with a JSON? You seem to understand where I'm coming from. Also, what I like about your solution is that it leaves the actual sentence content untouched.

Comment: How long is the text you are storing?  It might make more sense to just store as-is in the database and split into sentences and newlines on the client.

Comment: @JordanBurnett Thanks! It's too long for that I'm afraid. Also I'm saving more data on the backend about sentences, words etc.

Comment: @JordanBurnett if the goal is to preserve the nature of an actual printed text that won't work.

Comment: Take your first line list. Then have a separate list for sentences, where for example the third sentence would have `{startLine: 1, startChar: 37, endLine: 3, endChar: 12}`. When you want to look by line, you go straight to the `lines` table. When you want to look by sentence, you look up the sentence table and slice out portions of the indicated lines.

Comment: @Pointy Thank you. Is there a reason to do it this way around, rather than the other way around: Saving everything in sentences and then save in a line table how and where to break up those sentences? (as opposed to saving everything in the line table, and then save in the sentence table where the sentences start & end?)

Comment: You could do it either way. It depends on the ways your application needs to access the text.

Comment: I personally like your second approach which you could enhance by adding a field `linebreakAfter: x` where `x` would be the number of the character after which to insert a line break when rendering the text. Also, in the world of MongoDB it can be an ok thing to save the same data using different representations targeted at different use cases. Obviously this will result in a kind of double book-keeping.